# How does localization works for languages and countries?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

What I mean is this: suppose I localize my app to french (not specifying a country), will that version be used by any one that is using variations of that language?

French is spoken by more than 30 countries worldwide. Lets take Switzerland for example, where french and german are official languages. French for Switzerland is localized as `fr-CH` and will have that folder inside the application. If my app is localized just for french, will a person in Switzerland with a device configured for `fr-CH` see the french version or the default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the iOS settings, you'll see only one option for French, there's no variation. So you can just use `fr`.

I had an app localized for Brazilian Portuguese, when it should be Portuguese (`pt`) instead. `pt-BR` wasn't working. So be careful. You may want to try and change few strings and see what will come out.